# Apex 5 scatter marker chart dynamic series name

Tags: oracle-apex-5

Is there a way to dynamically display the series name in Apex Scatter Marker chart type?

I tried using hidden page item but the chart is not rendering at all.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

got it finally by modifying the generated XML:

...
                
                    
                    
                        
                            
                                
                            
                        
                        
                            
                                
                            
                        
                    
                    
                
..